# How to generate Tree path using traverse CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose my data in table like in attached picture without having path column. 
i want to generate a column, like "Path" in picture using traverse CTE in sql

Picture example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) to solve this:

```
WITH recCTE
AS (
    SELECT id,
        parentid,
        id AS original_id,
        parentid AS original_parentid,
        name as original_name,
        1 AS depth,
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS path
    FROM yourtable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT yourtable.id,
        yourtable.parentid, 
        recCTE.original_id,
        recCTE.original_parentID,
        recCTE.original_name,
        recCTE.depth + 1,
        CAST(recCTE.path + '-' + yourtable.name as VARCHAR(5000))
    FROM recCTE
    INNER JOIN yourtable
        ON recCTE.parentid = yourtable.id
    WHERE depth < 20 /*prevent cycling*/
    )
SELECT original_id as id, original_parentid as parentid, original_name as name, depth, path 
FROM recCTE t1
WHERE depth = (SELECT max(depth) FROM recCTE WHERE t1.original_id = recCTE.original_id)
```

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c299/10)

That CTE has two parts:

1. The "Anchor Member" which is the first selection from the table. This defines the output (which columns and column type are in the output).
2. The "Recursive Member" which selects from the CTE in which it's contained at is performed iteratively until the join fails.

In this example we capture the path by concatenating the path to the name over and over again in the recursive member. We also track Depth (how many recursions have been performed) and track the current `id` and `parentid` as well as the original `id` and original `parentid` so they can be selected in the final `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "path" of recursive query "recCTE".

Comment: Probably need to cast that name field to varchar(5000) in the recursive member. SQL Server is picky about that in recursive statements. I will update.

Comment: you need `CAST((recCTE.path + '-' + yourtable.name) as VARCHAR(5000))`

Comment: Updated Thanks @LONG I always forget that with SQL Server.

Comment: @JNevill, NP xD, its' easy to overlook that

Comment: @JNevil  your query not producing my desire result as i show in picture

Comment: @JNevil actually my question is misunderstood . Column Path in my table is not actual column , this column is what i generate by CTE .

Comment: Right. The `Path` column in this CTE is generating the path as it's shown in your picture. I'm not selecting Path from your table as it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have updated the answer to get exactly as you requested (added the subquery in the where clause of the final `SELECT` statement) so that it only retains the record for each id with the greatest depth.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
;with cte(id,parentId,name,path,cnt)
AS
(
select id,parentid,name,cast(name as VARCHAR(1024)) as path, 1 as cnt from test_cte
union all
select a.id,a.parentid,a.name,CAST((a.name + '-' +path ) as VARCHAR(1024)), case when a.parentid is null then 0 else cnt + 1 end as cnt from test_cte a join cte c on c.id = a.parentid where c.cnt is not null
)

select id,parentid,name,path from (select id,parentid,name,path, row_number() over(partition by id order by cnt desc) as rank from cte) a where a.rank = 1 order by 1 asc ;
```

Comment: seems OK but one problem is , its repeating own row character twice like (C-C-B-A)  two time C and i want like (C-B-A)

Comment: when you have duplicate name`s character will repeat